# Weird script result with validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a script that works great, but I have one small problem.

I just added to my script:

```
        if (isError) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }
```

Now I have a problem.  The last input validation set $('#input_1 input') is hiding the error-div when I type something in the input. All the other inputs are red with background changes, but the error-div disappears - only when I remove the error from #input1, which is the last one in the script.

the last input turns off the div-error if there is no error ONLY in that input.

Can't figure it out.  Any suggestions would be great.

```
$(function () {
$('#rbSubmit').formValidator({
    scope: '#form_register',
    onError: function () {
        var isError = false;
        if ($('#input_38 textarea').hasClass('error-input')) {
            isError = true;
            $('#r38 div').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            $("#error-div").show();
        } else {
            $('#r38 div').css('background-color', '#2F2F2F');
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }
        if ($('#input_39 input').hasClass('error-input')) {
            isError = true;
            $('#r39 div, #r39 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            $("#error-div").show();
        } else {
            $('#r39 div').css('background-color', '#2F2F2F');
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }



       // LAST DIV ALONE WILL TURN OFF THE div-error!!!  HELP!!!


        if ($('#input_1 input').hasClass('error-input')) {
            isError = true;
            $('#r1 div, #r1 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            $("#error-div").show();
        } else {
            $('#r1 div').css('background-color', '#2F2F2F');
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }
        if (isError) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }
    }
});
});
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you executing $("#error-div").show(); and $("#error-div").hide(); within each if else block? Surely if an error has been detected you can perform it at the end:

```
if (isError) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 2500);
    $("#error-div").show();
} else {
    $("#error-div").hide();
}
```

What jQuery plugin are you using for the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the error-div a z-index of higher than that of the other inputs:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Please note that you have to specify a position property.

Comment: this has nothing to do with z-index

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I thought about it, but its too long.  Is there a way to make the isError function not be affected by the last input validation?

Comment: Where can i place this?   if (isError) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }

Comment: Can I move:    if (isError) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $("#error-div").hide();
        }  to another area in the script?